# how to backwards fill in pandas with group and split dataframes by group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'genre': ['sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi', 'comedy', 
                                   'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy'],
                           'score': [5,5,4,3,2,9,10,8,4,7,5,6], 
                            'id': ["","","","stop","", "", "stop", "", "", "", "", ""]})
```

I would like to group by the different genres and backwards fill upto the id value of **stop**

So my final dataframe should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'genre': ['sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi', 'comedy', 
                                   'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy'],
                           'score': [5,5,4,3,2,9,10,8,4,7,5,6], 
                            'id': ["stop","stop","stop","stop","", "stop", "stop", "", "", "", "", ""]})
```

So the backwards filling only occurs from the word **stop** and does not go past this.

After this is there a way to split the dataframes into individual groups more easily than a for loop? I would like to make smaller dataframes based on the genre column e.g. a dataframe for sci-fi values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'genre': ['sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi','sci-fi', 'comedy', 
                                   'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy', 'comedy'],
                           'score': [5,5,4,3,2,9,10,8,4,7,5,6], 
                            'id': ["","","","stop","", "", "stop", "", "", "", "", ""]})

# Backfilling based on "stop" for each genre group
def backfill_upto_stop(group):
    mask = group['id'] == 'stop'
    group.loc[mask.idxmax():, 'id'] = group.loc[mask.idxmax():, 'id'].bfill()
    return group

df = df.groupby('genre').apply(backfill_upto_stop)

# Split dataframe into smaller dataframes by genre
dfs = {genre: df_group for genre, df_group in df.groupby('genre')}

# To access a specific genre dataframe:
print(dfs['sci-fi'])
print(dfs['comedy'])
```

Comment: do you mean bfill() for backwards filling not forwards filling? as i need to identify data backwards before "stop" not after

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate column can be generated by:

```
df.groupby('genre')['id'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('', np.nan).bfill().fillna(''))
```

This generates a data frame like so:

```
df.join(df.groupby('genre')['id'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('', np.nan).bfill().fillna('')).rename('id_bfill'))
Out[14]: 
     genre  score    id id_bfill
0   sci-fi      5           stop
1   sci-fi      5           stop
2   sci-fi      4           stop
3   sci-fi      3  stop     stop
4   sci-fi      2               
5   comedy      9           stop
6   comedy     10  stop     stop
7   comedy      8               
8   comedy      4               
9   comedy      7               
10  comedy      5               
11  comedy      6
```

I'm not sure why you would want to keep the column `id` with empty values as an empty string, however. It would be better to replace them all with `np.nan`: `pd.Series.bfill` won't overwrite empty strings but will do so for `NaN` values. If you stored them in that format the calls can be shortened to just `df.groupby('genre')['id'].bfill()`.

I am also unclear as to the ordering of your data frame. Is there a date column omitted from the question? Make sure that there is proper ordering of the things to be filled.

---

If you want separate data frames, just iterate over the group-by:

```
for the_group_id, matching_df in df.groupby('genre'):
    ...  # insert stuff you want to do here
```

This could be turned into a one-liner:

```
df_dict = {g: d for g, d in df.groupby('genre')}
```

That would allow you to access the matching data frames in the dictionary by the group key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df.replace("", np.nan).groupby('genre', 
                               sort=False, 
                               group_keys=True)\
                      .apply(lambda x:x.id.bfill().fillna(''))\
                      .reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
genre   level_1 id
0   sci-fi  0   stop
1   sci-fi  1   stop
2   sci-fi  2   stop
3   sci-fi  3   stop
4   sci-fi  4   
5   comedy  5   stop
6   comedy  6   stop
7   comedy  7   
8   comedy  8   
9   comedy  9   
10  comedy  10  
11  comedy  11
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace `""` by `nan`, then use `groupby().bfill()`:

```
df['id'] = (df['id'].replace("", value=np.nan)
                .groupby(df['genre']).bfill()
                .fillna("")
           )
```

Output:

```
     genre  score    id
0   sci-fi      5  stop
1   sci-fi      5  stop
2   sci-fi      4  stop
3   sci-fi      3  stop
4   sci-fi      2      
5   comedy      9  stop
6   comedy     10  stop
7   comedy      8      
8   comedy      4      
9   comedy      7      
10  comedy      5      
11  comedy      6
```

To split the data, you can do:

```
groups = {genre:data for genre,data in df.groupby('genre')}
```

Then you can get the `sci-fi` genre with `groups['sci-fi']`, or safer with `groups.get('sci-fi')` in the case `sci-fi` not a genre in your data.

Comment: Both steps in one: `for k, g in df.replace({'id': {'': float('nan')}}).groupby('genre'): print(g.bfill().fillna(''))`